# Is a good or a bad idea store Set<Long> in JPA as a string and convert it before to save and after get the entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class `Calculation` that have many filters from screen and the result of calculation.

```java
class Calculation {
    
    Set<Long> filterA;
    Set<Long> filterB;
    Set<Long> filterC;
    Set<Long> filterD;
    Set<Long> filterE;
}
```

I need to save the data of calculation and the filters.

As I don't need to search what calculation I have some specific filter, I am thinking about store this filters as a string.

```java
class CalculationEntity {
    
    String filterA;
}
```

And I could cast `filterA (String)` -> to -> `Set<Long>`
I don't have available a NoSQL like mongo at organization.

Is it a bad idea? Or can be a good idea?

I wouldn't want to use @ElementCollection because it would create five tables.

Comment: Neither good nor bad. Any choice has pros/cons and they all depend on how you use it in the application, how much data it'll hold and what you need it for. Querying for one value becomes tricky, but not impossible, but you'll have to manage it yourself; queries looking for particular values in the set, or value comparisons become a bit of a challenge, as does any indexing you might need on this, but no different from other columns holding string data.

Comment: Thanks @Cris. I choose store the entire filter in one column as a json. Because I don't need query some specific value. I need only to recovery the entire calculation and load on screen.

Comment: @leandro.dev not sure if you use them but `javax.persistence.Convert` is very handy for those type of tasks. You can still define tasks on your entity as `Set` but store them as `String` in Db.